# Package and distribute back-end code such that a user could launch that locally

Tags: web-server, desktop-client, progressive-web-application, electron

Our company has a web SaaS solution for company clients. Data of company clients need to be sent back and forth between browser of the users and our server.

Some clients hesitate to send their data to our server like this. So we are wondering, technically, what are possible solutions.

For instance, is there any software or library to package and distribute our back-end code such that a user could get it and launch that locally as if it was a standalone desktop application?

Hope this would not be too complicated for a user.

Comment: You mean something like electron? you can put anything on it ad development time, and after deploy you can just update...

Comment: This is very broad, any SaaS webapp can technically be made on-premise by sending the server-side software. What framework does your webapp use? On what database(s) does it rely? Does it rely on external APIs, does it have SSO, etc?